Is this a good way of providing bounds checking while using __restrict__ keyword in C++
I am writing some C++ code and compiling with g++. I use the __restrict__ keyword on pointer arrays in some performance critical places to hopefully get better performance.
std::vector::operator[] has the neat ability to provide range checking in debug build if the flag _GLIBCXX_DEBUG is specified with g++. However, I guess the options to get the __restrict__ benefit is lost if using std::vector, as a raw pointer must be used with it.
I was looking for an option to get both benefits: Meaning I get range checking in debug build, and disable pointer aliasing for release build.
The simple example program below illustrates what I came up with (note that the example is not meant to show a case where __restrict__ actually leads to speedup):
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define VEC_RSTR(T, name) T *__restrict__ name
#define VEC_RSTR_CONST(T, name) const T *__restrict__ name
#define VEC_RSTR_CALL(name) name.data()
#else
#define VEC_RSTR(T, name) vector<T> &name
#define VEC_RSTR_CONST(T, name) const vector<T> &name
#define VEC_RSTR_CALL(name) name
#endif

void add(VEC_RSTR_CONST(double, a), VEC_RSTR_CONST(double, b), VEC_RSTR(double, c), size_t N)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}

void add_segfault(VEC_RSTR_CONST(double, a), VEC_RSTR_CONST(double, b), VEC_RSTR(double, c), size_t N)
{
    N += 100000; // This will trigger out of bounds access
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}

int main()
{

    vector<double> a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    vector<double> b = a;
    vector<double> c(a.size());

    add(VEC_RSTR_CALL(a), VEC_RSTR_CALL(b), VEC_RSTR_CALL(c), a.size());
    cout << "print correct:\n";
    for (const auto &val : c)
    {
        cout << val << "\n";
    }

    add_segfault(VEC_RSTR_CALL(a), VEC_RSTR_CALL(b), VEC_RSTR_CALL(c), a.size());
    cout << "print incorrect:\n";
    for (const auto &val : c)
    {
        cout << val << "\n";
    }
}

I basically use some macros to specify that a vector<T>& is used in debug mode and a T * __restrict__ is used in release mode.
I ran the code two times. First in debug mode like this:
g++ main.cpp -o main -DNDEBUG -O3
./main

giving the following output:
print correct:
2
4
6
8
./launch-rls.sh: line 7: 51154 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./main

I then built and ran the second example like this:
g++ main.cpp -o main -g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
./main

which gave the following output providing info about the out-of-bounds access:
print correct:
2
4
6
8
/usr/include/c++/11/debug/vector:438:
In function:
    std::debug::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::reference std::debug::vector<_Tp, 
    _Allocator>::operator[](std::debug::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::size_type) 
    [with _Tp = double; _Allocator = std::allocator<double>; std::
    debug::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::reference = double&; std::
    debug::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::size_type = long unsigned int]

Error: attempt to subscript container with out-of-bounds index 4, but 
container only holds 4 elements.

Objects involved in the operation:
    sequence "this" @ 0x7ffd12128010 {
      type = std::debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >;
    }

I'm wondering, should I use this in actual code or not?
What do you think about this? Is it valid, or is it considered preprocessor hacking that makes the code hard to read and leads to more issues than it solves? Any suggestions for improvements?

__restrict__ is difficult to use correctly, and if you use it incorrectly then it can easily produce difficult to find bugs.  Do you actually have a problem here for it to solve?  And if so, does it in fact solve that problem?  If the answer to either of those is "no" then I'd dump all usage of __restrict__ as quickly as possible.

@JohnBollinger Can you please elaborate on why it is hard to use correctly? My impression was that if you had a function taking in some pointers and you are sure that none of the pointers should point to the same memory, you could mark them with __restrict__ allowing for possible optimizations.

Not an answer but some advice: Performance is hard to get right, and compilers are getting very good at taking obvious patterns and optimizing the heck out of them.  That means you should write the code the natural C++ way and then once you have working code, profile to see if it meets your needs and then you have concrete data on where the actual bottlenecks in your code are.  A lot of people are surprised when they turn on their optimizer and see the performance std::vector gets.

@ander, it is easy to be wrong about the non-aliasing being an acceptable limitation.  It is also easy to violate that restriction accidentally.  Not least because its not just the __restrict__ed pointers themselves that have non-aliasing requirements, but also other pointers derived from them.  And the compiler usually is not in a position to diagnose violations, so if there are any then your program may just break.  If you are getting an important performance improvement this way then maybe that's worth the extra risk and maintenance burden, but if not, then __restrict__ is foolish.

@JohnBollinger I see. I actually tried disabling all use of __restrict__ in my code now, and I see no significant degradation of performance, so I guess I should actually verify that it improves performance before using it all over the place.. However I would only use it in very low level performance critical loops that only operate on basic datatypes. I guess what your argument "Not least because its not just the __restrict__ed pointers themselves that have non-aliasing requirements, but also other pointers derived from them. " won't count for primitive types used in simple loop contexts.

@ander, __restrict__ places restrictions related to modification of the objects to which pointers point.  These can be and often are scalars.  Note well that I am not saying that __restrict__ cannot be used safely and correctly, only that you should be sure that you thoroughly understand what you're doing (I suspect you're not there yet), and that you're getting something worthwhile out of it.  I'm inclined to think that if you have not identified a specific performance problem to solve, then throwing __restrict__ at your code is an exercise in premature optimization.

@JohnBollinger I see. I was pretty sure its usage was straight forward, but I guess I will consider twice before using it then. If you have any links, examples or anything to point me to where incorrect usage of __restrict__ is shown I would be happy to know.
